# Sending data from react server to node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to send the data from input boxes in react server to nodejs server but everytime i am getting error  on backend

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

Here is my code for that

```
onformsubmit=()=>{
console.log(this.state.email,this.state.password) ///gets printed correctly

axios.post('http://localhost:5000/acc-details',{
  email:this.state.email,
  password:this.state.password
})
.then(response=>{
  console.log('success')
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
```

and then in node server

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()
var bodyparser=require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyparser.json())

router.post('/acc-details',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.email)
    res.send('ok')
})
```

if not consoling in node server  i am getting response back 'ok' as writtten above but i want to fetch my email and password on node server for db authentication

Comment: you have `router.post('...')` in here but you are putting `bodyparser.json()` on `app.use()`.  typo?  if not, change `router.` to `app.`

Comment: It is better to test your server with tools like **postman** to determine if your server code is faulty or front-end.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your Axios request slightly to send **multipart/form-data** data.

```
onformsubmit = () => {

    // Collect properties from the state
    const {email, password} = this.state;

    // Use FormData API
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('email', email);
    formdata.append('password', password);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/acc-details', formdata)
    .then( response=> {
        console.log('success')
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: it says formdata is not defined on server side :(

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai Make sure you have implemented this on client-side, `formdata` should not accessible to server-side.

Comment: what should i console on server to check ?

Answer (score 0):

```
onformsubmit=()=>{
console.log(this.state.email,this.state.password) ///gets printed correctly
axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/acc-details'
  method: 'POST',
  data: { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password } 
})
.then(response=>{
  console.log('success')
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
```

Now you should be able to access req.body

---

Edit:

after 200 tries, i figured out:

````
axios({
      url: "http://localhost:5000/acc-details",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"
      },
      data: { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password }
    });```
````

Comment: on server side console.log(req.body.data) ??

Comment: console.log(req.body.email, req.body.password)

Comment: but then too i am getting the same error what i was previously getting

Comment: what's the output of console.log(req.body)?

Comment: undefined dude !

Comment: after 200 tries, i figured out:
`axios({
      url: "http://localhost:5000/acc-details",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"
      },
      data: { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password }
    });`